# C++ pointers exercise

Tags: c++, pointers

I found the following complete exercise about C++ pointers on the web, but I can't still understand how it works.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void reverse(char *s, int n) {
    char *first = &s[0];
    char *last = &s[n-1];
    int k = 0;

    while(first < last){
        char temp = *first;

        *first++ = *last;
        *last-- = temp;

        k++;
    }
}


int main() {
    int n;
    char str[] = "Hello";
    cout << str << endl << endl;
    n = strlen(str);
    reverse(str,n);
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The part that I really can't understand is

```cpp
*first++ = *last;
*last-- = temp;
```

Comment: Break those lines down into each operation, and apply operator precedence. Hint: it works the way you'd expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers are basically addresses in memory, for this specific case they point to addresses in memory where you can find characters. `*first` is the value (ie: the character) which is at the address and with `++` and `--` you increment or decrement the pointer, thus walking through the memory to point to the next/previous character.

`*first++ = *last;` is evaluated as:

1. Put in the memory address/location where `first` points the value which is at the memory location where `last` points
2. increment `first`, so that it points to the next address.

This is equivalent to:

```
*first = *last;
first ++;
```

`*last-- = temp;` is evaluated as:

1. Put in the memory address/location where `last` points the value of `temp`
2. Decrement `last`, so that it points to the previous address

I leave to you as an exercise to find out with which two operations is this equivalent :)

Answer (score 2):

```
*first = *last; // copy data from last to first
++first; // point to the next item
*last = temp; // copy data from temp to last
--last; // point to the previous item
```

Comment: +1 This is how it should be written.  The old K&R C "put as much code in one line with no parentheses so you HAVE to know C precedence rules to understand this" is so 1980.  Optimizing compilers are amazing now-a-days.  Sadly, you will see this pattern of code a LOT in string/byte buffer code.  Learn it.  Understand it.  But when YOU have to write it, write it out.  Don't assume the reader knows C/C++ operator precedence off the top of his/her head, so use parentheses (it does not hurt), or even better, write the logic that is best for humans to read and understand, not a 1980 C compiler.

Comment: @franji1 Perhaps, but I've seen this pattern used many times so its meaning is second nature to me now. Personally I prefer to use algorithms such as `std::copy`

Comment: @Neil Thank you for your answer, and yes this is more understandable than the original one. I didn't exactly know that first++ gets runned after the assignment, actually i thought it was the opposite. I chose fritzone answer as the best because he answered me faster, and he gave me a complete explanation, but thank you too!

Comment: @Sevenarth Thank you for your kind words.